# request.POST.get() is returning nothing

Tags: html, django

The problem is though I am putting correct data in the form, it always redirects to the except block of views.py

I tried to change and refresh data in the database but didn't work out.

Here is my views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def card_payment(request):
    card_no = request.POST.get('cardNumber')
    pay_method = 'Debit card'
    MM = request.POST['MM']
    YY = request.POST['YY']
    CVV = request.POST['cvv']

    request.session['dcard'] = card_no
    try:
        balance = Cards.objects.get(Card_number=card_no, Ex_month=MM, Ex_Year=YY, CVV=CVV).Balance
        request.session['total_balance'] = balance
        mail1 = Cards.objects.get(Card_number=card_no, Ex_month=MM, Ex_Year=YY, CVV=CVV).email

        if int(balance) >= int(request.session['pay_amount']):
            # print("if ma gayu")
            rno = random.randint(100000, 999999)
            request.session['OTP'] = rno

            amt = request.session['pay_amount']
            username = request.user.get_username()
            print(username)
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            mail_id = user.email
            print([mail_id])
            msg = 'Your OTP For Payment of ৳' + str(amt) + ' is ' + str(rno)
            # print(msg)
            # print([mail_id])
            # print(amt)
            send_mail('OTP for Debit card Payment',
                      msg,
                      'nafibinnoor@gmail.com',
                      [mail_id],
                      fail_silently=False)
            return render(request, 'OTP.html')
        return render(request, 'wrongdata.html')


    except:
        return render(request, 'wrongdata.html')
```

HTML form for this view

```
<form action="pessanger_detail_def/card_payment" method="POST" class="creditly-card-form agileinfo_form">
                                         {% csrf_token %}
                                       <section class="creditly-wrapper wthree, w3_agileits_wrapper">
                                          <!--<label>Name On Card</label></br>
                                          <input type="text" class="pipo1" placeholder="John smith" name="name"></br>-->
                                       <label>Card Number</label>
                                       <input type="text" class="pipo1" placeholder="**** **** **** *****" name="cardNumber"></br>
                                       <label>CVV</label></br>
                                       <input type="text" class="pipo1" placeholder="***" name="cvv"><br>
                                       <label>Expiration Date</label></br>
                                       <input type="text" class="pipo2" placeholder="MM" name="MM"><label> </label><input type="text" class="pipo2" placeholder="YY" name="YY">
                                       </br><br>
                                       <input type="submit" name='Submit' value='MAKE A PAYMENT' >

                                       </section>
                                    </form>
```

And for this, model.py is:

```
class Cards(models.Model):
    Card_number = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=16)
    Ex_month = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    Ex_Year = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    CVV = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    Balance = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=50,default='rambarodavala21@gmail.com')
```

The problem is though I am putting correct data in the form, it always redirects to the except block of views.py

I tried to change and refresh data in the database but didn't work out.